# What is the easiest way to identify a gender for a noun (in french)?

Tags: nlp

I am working on an app where in order to process some data, I need to be able to identify the gender for some selected words.
My data is in French.

The feature I am looking for should be able to tell me that "les garçons" is male plural, "chienne" is singular female.

What is the easiest word to do so?
If you have a link to a library do not hesitate.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to apply a French POS tagger, e.g. as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44468300/how-to-pos-tag-a-french-sentence

Note that a POS tagger usually works better from full sentences than isolated words.

Answer (score 1):

One option is the [pattern library](https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/pages/pattern-fr) in Python.

Patterns can find plural/singular out-of-the-box:

```py
from pattern.fr import singularize, pluralize

def singular_or_plural(token):
    return 'plural' if pluralize(token) == token else 'singular'

assert singular_or_plural("garçons") == 'plural'
assert singular_or_plural("chienne") == 'singular'
```

Pattern could possibly be used to find gender.